# Easy emoji puzzle

Tags: emoji

Can you figure out what this string of emoji represents?

[image]

Text version:

> ✝️⛪☸️☠️⭐☀️‍⚖️

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are ...

> ... the [Major Arcana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_Arcana) of a Tarot deck.

In particular:

> The Fool
>   The Magician
>  ✝️ The High Priestess
>   The Empress
>   The Emperor
>  ⛪ The Hierophant
>   The Lovers
>   The Chariot
>   Justice
>   The Hermit
>  ☸️ The Wheel of Fortune
>   Strength
>   The Hanged Man
>  ☠️ Death
>   Temperance
>   The Devil
>   The Tower
>  ⭐ The Star
>   The Moon
>  ☀️ The Sun
>  ‍⚖️ Judgement
>   The World

Comment: Nice job! Was it the string of obvious ones at the end that gave it away? I wondered if the stretches I had to make for Joker, Horse, Hammer, Santa, Climber, and Beer might throw people off.

Comment: Thanks. I had a pretty good idea when I saw the first two and the last one. Then I saw the skull and the devil. Then I counted the symbols. I think once you know the answer, the surrogate emojis you chose make sense.